# Segmenting media files with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

In the newer releases of FFMPEG it is supposed to be possible to segment media files.
I checked out the SVN with

```
svn checkout svn://svn.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg/trunk ffmpeg
```

However, after building and trying to segment with the command below I get the error:

```
Unrecognized option 'segment_time'
```

Is there a specific ./configure option needed or a specific branch?
There is nothing mentioned in FFMPEG manual (neither which version supports it). I would prefer to use a pre-build production version if possible.

Command used to test:

```
ffmpeg -v 9 -loglevel 99 -re -i test.mov -an -c copy -b:v 128k -flags -global_header -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 4 -segment_list test.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts stream%05d.ts
```

Comment: Documentation at http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment

Comment: Thanks, it seems that we can now encode and segment on the fly, will try that soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFmpeg no longer uses SVN and has moved to Git. The last commit to SVN was on 2011-01-19, and I believe that is too old for your purposes. See the [FFmpeg download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for more information and instructions on accessing the FFmpeg Git repository.

Also, please remember to show the complete ffmpeg console output for any questions regarding ffmpeg commands. It provides useful information such as ffmpeg version and ./configure options and providing it can allow quicker answers.

Comment: Thnaks, I have a look. I took the tutorial on the website to build on a mac, but didn't realize it was that out of date. I found a 0.10.2 version for the Mac which seems to work perfect, but need to build manually for my production server I think at it runs Debian 6.0 (Squeeze) for which I haven't fond a 0.10.2 version yet.

Comment: Brilliant! All set to go now!